# Bootstrap on scroll active class need to add before 100px from top

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap scroll navigation changes the active state only when it reaches top of the screen. I need it to be changed when it reaches `100px` from the top.

When I click on navigation it stops before `100px` which is correct but the `active` state doesn't change.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'a.page-scroll', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

For eg: In this [demo](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/) ([download link](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav))the active state only changes if the the div goes to top. How do I make it so the active state change when it is `100px` from the top.

Comment: Did you view the demo sites source code? `scrolling-nav.js` has code that affects the navigational collapse toggle based on how many pixels you are from the top of the screen...

Comment: I already change that value. Now what happen is the div get stop before `100px` but the active class doesnt change. The active class get change when it reach to `0`

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or demo of your code in action? I assume the demo linked is just the developers example?

Comment: I have updated the download link also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to change the active state of the links in your nav when it gets to 100px from from the top, correct?
  Bootstrap's scrollspy has some javascript references that you can set to the body tag to control the offset if you look at the body tag in the example that you have given you can see that it looks like the following:

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
```

It sets the scrollspy plugin and the target.  You can also set the `data-offset`.  So it would look something like the following:

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top" data-offset="100">
```

You can read Bootstrap's javascript reference [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_scrollspy.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly I wanted.