# Change active state if the page is 50px from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to stop the div when it reaches `50px` from the top. It works while I made the change on `scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50` but the active state on navigation doesn't change. It only change if I scroll that `50px`  too. Please help.

I am using [this](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav) template

Comment: Please comment what did you find stupid in this post that made you to downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853195/bootstrap-on-scroll-active-class-need-to-add-before-100px-from-top)

Just update the body to

`<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top" data-offset="100">`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have selected all the anchors ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)

now , you achieved what you wanted just because some anchor in the div you want to stop reaches 50px from top but because you selected all the anchors the navigation is also behaving the same way.Try replacing the anchor with the id of your div and you're done.
$('#idOfDiv').offset().top -50 instead of $anchor.attr('href') and so on.

Maybe this is why it was downvoted, but acknowledge if it works, else elaborate your question so it can be understood better.
Love.Peace.Code